# How to get selected item value from Sparse boolean array?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I want to get previous selected Index value and match with the current position value going to be selected if found then unselect previous one and select the current one how do i do that.

code:-

```
public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
    }
    return items;
}
```

code for current position going to be selected

```
OptionsDataModel model = dataSet.get(position);
positiveOptionsAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
    selectedItems.delete(pos);
    animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
    removePoints(pos);
} else {
    animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
    selectedItems.put(pos, true);
    savePoints(pos);
}
```

Comment: can you share code for your adapter too?

Comment: code is very long not fit in this window

Comment: code for `toggleSelection()`

Comment: public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        currentSelectedIndex = pos;
        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
            removePoints(pos);

        } else {
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            savePoints(pos);

        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

Comment: please check.....

Comment: and what is the error you are getting when selecting?

Comment: I am not getting any error what i want i have recyclerview with "+1","+2","+3".... and if i first time selected +3 and when i second time select +2 then i want +3 to unselect and want current item +2 selected.

Comment: can't help without code for `Adapter` and `Activity`.